# Mobile click on body does not fire

Tags: javascript, click, smartphone

I have this code

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent)
```

where `el.clickOutsideEvent` is well defined. This works impeccably for desktop browsers, even with mobile emulators. However, if I try to run this with an iPhone, the event does not run, unless I tap the logo or something else. Tapping a simple div does not fire the event. I've searched for this for a long while and found some questions, but they were mainly involving jQuery. A frequent suggestion was to put `touchstart` into the first parameter, but several tries failed.. How should I modify my code?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation provided by apple concerning event handling? It might have something to do with ios not bubbling events upward in the past, but I'm not certain if that still applies these days. Is there any other way to bind the event closer than directly onto the body? I presume the clickOutsideEvent is like a popover you want to close when the user taps outside of the popover? If that is the case, I make my popovers fullscreen with a transparent background so that any clicks visually outside of the popover, are in facts still delegated to the popover itsself.

Comment: @Shilly there is a div inside the body. I tried if (!document.querySelector("body > div").onclick) document.body.querySelector("body > div").onclick = ''; document.querySelector("body > div").addEventListener('click', el.clickOutsideEvent); No luck

Comment: In the past you had to do like CSS hacks to change the pointer, to flag the div as clickable, to make the click event bubble up to the body. But i thought they fixed those things. :x What does the clickOutsideEvent handler do? Maybe there's alternatives to events.

Comment: @Shilly I have a search bar which needs to be shown when a search button is clicked and hidden if clicked anywhere else. There is no alternative, as I need this to be done inside a vue directive. I am completely new to vue, but with great difficulty managed to make the directive work, yet, I have a problem with the "click anywhere else".

Comment: @Shilly who can I achieve this with CSS hacks? something like body > div::active {} ?

Comment: Hence, can't you make the search bar take up the entire screen and put 90% of it in a transparent color so the page is still visible, but any click will always be on the search bar container. The best thing would be to get touchstart working, but that's not something we can really debug without an emulator for the phone you're using.

Comment: http://gravitydept.com/blog/js-click-event-bubbling-on-ios